# How to capture the activation of the menubar?

Tags: winapi

I'm now trying to do some owner draw of the window frame , including the caption , the border , the mini/max/restore zone and the menubar. Escpecially for the menubar , I have done some gdi operations to redefine the area of the menubar , and repaint on WM_NCPAINT. However, when I press the Alt key or F10, the original menubar activated. I found it has something with the WM_SYSKEYDOWN , and then I blocked it. After that I put a control into the frame window, for expample, a edit control, when the control get focused, I press Alt or F10 , the original menubar of the frame window get activated again.
[image: when control get focused ,press alt or F10]
Wow , seems have something with the wm_notify message.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
    case WM_NCPAINT: {
        //NC and Menubar redrawing.
        BOOL active_flag;
        HDC hdc; 
        RECT rect={0,0,0,0};
        
        active_flag=(BOOL)wParam;        
        hdc=GetWindowDC(hwnd);
        Frame_NCDraw(hwnd,hdc,rect,0,&active_flag);
        Frame_MenuBarDraw(hwnd,hdc);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        
        return !active_flag;        
    } break;
    case WM_INITMENUPOPUP: {
       //set the background of the menu item. a little long , no source code paste.
       ...
       //
    } break;    
    case WM_NCHITTEST: {
       // redefine the area of the HTMENU.
    } break;
    case WM_MEASUREITEM: {
        LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmis;
        lpmis = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
        
        //Menu item adjust the height/width.
        if(lpmis->CtlType == ODT_MENU) {
            UINT menu_item_id = lpmis->itemID;
            lpmis->itemWidth = 200;
            lpmis->itemHeight = ((menu_item_id==0x0)?5:28);
        }
    } break;
    case WM_DRAWITEM: {
        UINT ctrl_id=(UINT)wParam;
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDraw=(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
        
        if(pDraw->CtlType==ODT_MENU) {
            Frame_DrawMenuItem(pDraw); // MenuItem owner drawing.
        }
    } break;
.....
}
```

So How should I deal with the activation of the original menubar ? I mean , I want to forbid the painting for the original menubar. Instead , I want my MenuBar activated by the Alt or F10 key press.

Comment: Have you tried [`SetMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenu) or [`DestroyMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroymenu)?

Comment: Sorry, Im not sure whats your point . I'm doing the repaint of the window. The menubar is a part of the window. SetMenu seems to be a way of assign a menu for a window, DestroyMenu used to destroy a menu. why and how can I use these for repainting for a menubar?

Comment: I mean do you try to use these apis to remove the original menubar？

Comment: No , I will repaint the menubar.The original painting doesn't math the painting style of the window. I do my own painting to cover the original one. But when press F10 or Alt , the original menubar painting comes out, make a mess.

Comment: Thank you for providing. Would you mind sharing a minimal complete sample that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I can give you the full code , It's just a test demo, not long , about 800+ lines. How can i push it to you ? I'm not familiar with this forum.

Comment: You could upload the project(without private information) to github or onedrive, etc. And then post the link here.

Comment: Here It is[link](https://github.com/YouSyd/WinMenuBar_Test.git) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Alright, I'm doing this with spy. The trigger message was WM_MENUSELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message, you will also receive [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) with `SC_KEYMENU`, you need to handle this command to activate and display your own menu.

> `lParam` contains the character code of the key that is used with the
> ALT key to display the popup menu. For example , pressing ALT+F to
> display the File popup will cause a WM_SYSCOMMAND with `wParam` equal
> to `SC_KEYMENU` and `lParam` equal to'f'.

If only ALT/F10, the test result of lParam is 0.

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND: 
    if (wParam == SC_KEYMENU)
    {
        //Draw activated menubar

        switch (lParam)
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 'f':
            //pop up menu "File"
            break;
        case 'h':
            //pop up menu "Help"
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

Comment: Good ! It's useful to complete the whole accelerator keys message handlers.

Comment: Hi @Younth, Does this solve your issue, please also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.

Comment: answer accepted. Thank you.  Both WM_MENUSELECT and WM_SYSCOMMAND work as I have tried. Thank you